# how to differentiate among select and nonselect queries in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i'm writing a user defined function to execute sql queries.
Usually i have to write try catch blocks whereever i'm writing sql statements.
Instead of doing this i would like to write a function and pass the query to that function and write try catch blocks and return the result from that function. All i want do in that function is

1. If query executed sucessfully then

   a. return true for non select queries

   b. return fetched rows if it is select queries
2. If query fails executing return fasle

I'm able to return sucess or failure of query execution but i'm stucked when using select passing to the function. Can someone suggest a workaround process for this.

here is the psuedo code

```
function oxeDbQueryExecute($query, $dbObject){
    $returnValue = false;
    try{
        $resultSetObject = $dbObject->query($query);
        if($resultSetObject){ //  query executed successfully
            $returnValue = true;
            if(selectquery){ // if pdo statement contains any rows because of the executed query is a select query
                $returnValue = an array containg all the rows
            }               
        }
    }catch(PDOException $exception){
        error_log($exception->getMessage());
    }

    return $returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Could we maybe see what your code is so far? I have trouble understanding this without any context.

Comment: Not too sure about PDO, but `mysqli_query` does this by default: [Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: @ljacqu for your referrence i have added some psuedo code. hope that will clear

Comment: @RaviMCA Could you also give an example for a query causing your problem, please?

Comment: @ljacqu actually here i'm stucked. i'm Unable to complete the function. All i want know $resultSetObject whether contains any rows or not

Comment: @RaviMCA Aha, so the `$returnValue = an array containg all the rows` is where you're stuck at?

Comment: @ljacqu no. sorry if i'm unclear. after executing query i want know the result set object is contains rows or boolean. If it contains rows then return the array with all returned rows else return boolean

Answer (score 0):

```
// defining function
function oxeDbQueryExecute($query, $dbObject){
    $returnValue = false;
    try{
        $resultSetObject = $dbObject->query($query);
        if($resultSetObject){ //  checking query executed successfully or not
            $returnValue = true;
            /*
                **  checking result set is having any records or not.
                **  Result set will have rows if the query is "select" type query.
                **  In this case return array consisting rows in the format of objects
            */
            $rowOfObjects = $resultSetObject->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            if(count($rowOfObjects)){
                $returnValue = $rowOfObjects;
            }
        }
    }catch(PDOException $exception){
        error_log($exception->getMessage()."    Query : ".$query."");
    }       
    return $returnValue;
}

 // creating databse connection
 $db = new PDO("sqlite:D:/****/****/300/******_*_En/Query_ImageAnno.data");
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // to make thorw exceptions instead of fatal error

$queryResult = oxeDbQueryExecute("insert into chapter('tfoken')values('dfdf')", $db);
if($queryResult){
    if(count($queryResult)){ // if executed query is select type query
        print_r($queryResult);
    }
}else{
    echo "failed";
}
```